# How to create Dynamic Menu in Modx

Tags: modx, modx-templates

I want to create a e-commerce in Modx CMS. I have create dynamically everything in Modx, but i am not able to create dynamic menu.

How can i do this?

Comment: Have you checked pdoMenu from pdoTools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s the contents of the myWrapperTpl chunk:

```
 <ul[[+outerClasses:notempty=` class="[[+outerClasses]]"`]]> [[+output]]</ul>

<li[[*id:is=`[[+id]]`:then=` class="active"`]]>
    <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">
        [[+menutitle:default=`[[+pagetitle]]`]]
    </a>
    [[[[+level:lt=`[[+maxLevel]]`:then=`getResources@main-menu? &parents=`[[+id]]` &level=`[[+level:add]]``:else=`-`]]]]
    </li>
```